# How to set a base path to react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change my react app to work on subdirectories inside an URL like:
[www.mysite.com/reactapp](http://www.mysite.com/reactapp)

I already try to redirect, basename on the router and put the path in all components but always the path and the searches for the bundles happen in the root directory ([www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com))

How I can force or adapt react to read the path and treat it like the default?

Comment: Non-ejected create-react-app?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question. Basically I have other aplication in this others path, I need to force react treat this path like the root, because it always change to the domain :(

Answer (score 0):

define your `homepage` (your base path) in `package.json` like this:

```
"homepage": "/somepath"
```

This way, you can serve your app on `somepath`, and you can access it like

```
http://yourdomain.com/somepath
```

Note that this is only effective in production (when you build your app) and not in development.

Comment: Doesn’t work, I think that this project wasn’t create using create-react-app

Comment: Ah, I see. so if it's not CRA, then you should have access to `webpack` config. Do you?

Comment: Yes, I already fix the assets import with public path on webpack, but nothing works in the navigation

Comment: well without any code samples I don't think I can help you, but I can give you some pointers. use google dev tools (or the dev tools of whatever browser you're using) and check that what path your navigation is trying to go to. and from there, you can trace back to where the path is getting set (some where in webpack config I presume). Besides that, if you want to not mess with your project's configs, you can achieve this with url rewriting in you web server (nginx or apache or whatever). This maybe safer if you didn't write the project yourself and you want to avoid messing it up.

Comment: Do not exist some hack as add # to the path like Angular does?

Comment: No, I don't think so.